# Backbone, xxx is not a constructor?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying making multi paged app using backbone, marionette and coffeescript.

apps/home.coffee

```
define [
    'App'
    './index/index'
],
(App, HomeIndex) ->
    class HomeApp extends App
        constructor : () ->
            super
            console.log typeof HomeIndex #return object
            @homeIndex = new HomeIndex() #TypeError: HomeIndex is not a constructor
            @initialize()

        initialize: ->
            console.log 'app initialize'
            App.contentArea.show homeIndex
```

apps/home/index/index.coffee

```
define [],
()->
    class HomeIndex extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout
        template: '<div>Hello, Backbone! </div>'

        constructor: () ->
            console.log '!'

        initialize: (options) ->
            @template = _.template @template
            console.log "Home Index initialized"

        render: () =>
            @$el.html @template
```

I can not initialize HomeIndex, anybody know what I am doing wrong?

please advice

Updated :

```
 define [
        'App'
        'apps/home/index/index'
    ],
```

but still typeof HomeIndex return object, not function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you got such an issue, check the files loaded by Requirejs. You'd probably seen that `./index/index` is either not what you expected, or not loaded at all.

Basically, AMD does not support relative links. Only link relative to the `baseUrl`.